# Saving Android Activity state and Contents

Tags: android, android-activity, state

i am making a chatting application for android, now i create a new activity when a button is pressed to start the chatting. when i hit the back button the chats dialogs will disappear as the activity is destroyed and on the button click a new activity is always created.

i want to save whats happening in my activity ( chatting history ) as well as the ability to open multiple chat windows, on click of button i can create new chat activity with the others not destroyed ..

I appreciate your help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SaveRestoreState.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html these must help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Preferred way: Don't save the state of the chats in the current activity - [bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29) some [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to the activities and load information from it.
- Alternative: If this seems harsh for you, then you can use some [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to save all the information (which I not recommend, singletons are evil).
- Second Alternative: In [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) of the activity, you can save the current state of the chat in SQLite database. And after that, in [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) you can load it again.